# In C# how do you inherit a property type for another class

Tags: c#

If you have two classes such as the following -

```
public class AAA
{
   public string PropertyA1 { get; set; }
   public SOMECLASS PropertyA2 { get; set; }
}

public class BBB
{
   public string PropertyB1 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to change class BBB to look like the following -

```
public class BBB
{
   public string PropertyB1 { get; set; }
   public AAA PropertyB2 { get; set; }
   public (SOMECLASS from AAA) PropertyB3  //How can this be done?
}
```

How should I get the "SOMECLASS from AAA"?

What is the proper way to structure these two classes?
I want PropertyB3 to be the same class as "SOMECLASS from AAA" without knowing what SOMECLASS is.

Comment: Is `B2` going to carry around a copy of `AAA` all the time?  Or should it inherit from it?

Comment: What prevents you from declaring BBB the way you want?

Comment: I want PropertyB3 to be the same class as "SOMECLASS from AAA" without knowing what SOMECLASS is.

Comment: If BBB inherits from AAA how do I get the SOMECLASS from AAA into BBB?

Answer (score 0):

If `PropertyB3` is only for read you can write something like

```
public SOMECLASS PropertyB3 
{  
   get { return ProeprtyB2 == null ? null : PropertyB2.ProeprtyA2 }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class AAA<TSOMECLASS>
{
   public string PropertyA1 { get; set; }
   public TSOMECLASS PropertyA2 { get; set; }
}

public class BBB<TSOMECLASS>
{
   public string PropertyB1 { get; set; }
   public AAA<TSOMECLASS> PropertyB2 { get; set; }
   public TSOMECLASS PropertyB3
   {
       get { return PropertyB2 == null ? null : PropertyB2.PropertyA1; }
       set 
       { 
           if (PropertyB2 == null) PropertyB2 = new AAA<TSOMECLASS>();
           PropertyB2.PropertyA1 = value; 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: PropertyB3 is not read only. And I want PropertyB3 to be the same class as "SOMECLASS from AAA" without knowing what SOMECLASS is. So if SOMECLASS changes, the change will be captured in all both AAA and BBB.

Comment: You can use generics and define type of SOMECLASS in class declaration or use `object` but in some place you need to know specific type of SOMECLASS when you work with them

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to return the *SOMECLASS* of your *AAA* --> *PropertyB2.PropertyA2* of *BBB* as property like this:

```
public class BBB
{
   public string PropertyB1 { get; set; }
   public AAA PropertyB2 { get; set; }
   public PropertyB3
   {
     get
     {
       return PropertyB2.PropertyA2
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public class BBB : AAA
{
   public string PropertyB1 { get; set; }
   //inherit from AAA: public SOMECLASS from AAA) PropertyB3 
   // hide the other property from AAA
   private new string PropertyA1 { get; set; }
}
```